# stacked column chart fusion charts using sql server database

Tags: sql-server, fusioncharts, stacked

I have a requirement to develop **stacked column** charts using FusionCharts XT trial version. I could not find any examples using data source as database for **stacked column**. They have shown examples using XML/JSON. Please help me if you have experience in this area of using FusionCharts. Thanks in advance.

Below is my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using InfoSoftGlobal;
namespace workflowmangement
{
     public partial class chart1 : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
        string conString =            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            siva.Text = CreateChart();
        }
     public string CreateChart()

          {


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

                string sqlStatement = "SELECT Activity_Name,Activity_Id from Activity";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                string strXML;

               strXML = "<graph caption='Category Wise Quantity' subCaption='By Quantity'     decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30'     formatNumberScale='0'>";

               while (reader.Read())

               {

                   strXML += "<set name='" + reader["Activity_Name"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["Activity_Id"].ToString() + "' />";

               }

               strXML += "</graph>";

               return FusionCharts.RenderChart("/FusionCharts/FCF_Pie3D.swf", "", strXML, "FactorySum", "650", "450", false, false);

          }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using FusionCharts charts can be rendered by two ways.

- JavaScript
- Flash

Data needs to be in one of the two formats XML/JSON. The XML/JSON data file contains the data points and configuration. Configuration will let us customize the look and feel of the chart.

Your aspx page where you intend to add the chart should contain below line of code

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

which adds a Literal control to the page which acts as container for the chart. Make sure to use the same literal ID where in this case the Literal ID is "Literal1".

See the live demo here http://goo.gl/nH4zj

See the doc here: http://goo.gl/MmqU6

Your XML must look like below.

```
<categories>

    <category label='Product A' />

    <category label='Product B' />

    <category label='Product C' />

    <category label='Product D' />

    <category label='Product E' />

</categories>

<dataset seriesName='2004' color='AFD8F8' showValues='0'>

    <set value='25601.34' />

    <set value='20148.82' />

    <set value='17372.76' />

    <set value='35407.15' />

    <set value='38105.68' />

</dataset>

<dataset seriesName='2005' color='F6BD0F' showValues='0'>

    <set value='57401.85' />

    <set value='41941.19' />

    <set value='45263.37' />

    <set value='117320.16' />

    <set value='114845.27' />

</dataset>

<dataset seriesName='2006' color='8BBA00' showValues='0'>

    <set value='45000.65' />

    <set value='44835.76' />

    <set value='18722.18' />

    <set value='77557.31' />

    <set value='92633.68' />

</dataset>
```

You can render the chart by passing the above XML using this line of code.

```
Literal1.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart("Charts/StackedColumn2D.swf", "", xmlStr.ToString(), "productSales", "600", "300", false, true);
```

xmlStr is the encoded XML data variable that is fed to render the chart.

It does not matter where the data is stored and retrieved from. What you need to do is encode your data either in XML or JSON and pass it to RenderChart method. In your case data needs to be retrieved from the MSSQL database server and encoded to XML/JSON which ever is convenient and passed to RenderChart method.

Download this sample project for Stacked Column 2D Charts and play with it for a better idea.

Download the demo here: https://github.com/OpenCV/stackedbar2d

Answer (score 0):

FusionChart takes data in two forms only- XML or JSON,
You can use any server side language --- data source. The data can be retrieved from the datasource and used in XML/JSON frm to build the chart.

Simple steps-

---

1) http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/csnet/CS_DB.html

In this you'll get the idea how to use the database to plot a chart.

---

2) http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/

In this link you'll get the examples to use a Stacked Column chart.

You only need to provide the data from the data source in the stacked chart XML format,
and change the chart type to StackedColumn3D/2D.
You are Done!
If this is not you are looking for... then elaborate a bit more on your requirement?